# Вывести bmp (32b + alpha) на форму использую alphaBlend (WINAPI, VC++)

Tags: winapi

Помогите разобраться. Я понял как выводить `BMP 32bit + альфа` на форму, используя функцию WINAPI AlphaBlend и структуру `BLENDFUNCTION` со следующими параметрами:

```
// загружаю bmp из ресурса
HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));

// создаю совместимый контекст и связываю bmp с ним
HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

BLENDFUNCTION blendFn = { 0 };
blendFn.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blendFn.BlendFlags = 0;
blendFn.SourceConstantAlpha = 128;  // 50% прозрачность
blendFn.AlphaFormat = 0;    // фиксированная прозрачность для всех точек bmp

AlphaBlend(
    hDC, 10, 10, 128, 128,
    hMemDC, 0, 0, 128, 128,
    blendFn);

ReleaseDC(hWnd, hMemDC);
```

Результат: [image: Результат]

Подскажите как при выводе изображения использовать альфа канал из изображения, я ставил флаг в параметре, но ничего не изменилось

```
blendFn.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff; 
blendFn.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся, но разобрался сам. Функция `LoadBitmap` загружает изображение в память и возвращает только его `handle`. Далее функцией `GetObject` можно получить информацию о загруженном изображении в структуре `BITMAP`, но в ней указатель на массив точек будет пустой. Я воспользовался функцией `LoadImage`, добавленной в замен устаревшей `LoadBittam`. Среди прочих параметров в ней можно указать флаг загрузки и если загрузить изображение с флагом `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION`, то будет создана `DIB` секция в памяти и указатель на нее будет лежать в структуре BITMAP в параметре `bmBits`.

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(
    hInstance,                     
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), 
    IMAGE_BITMAP,                  // загружаем BITMAP 
    0,                             // ширина
    0,                             // высота
    LR_CREATEDIBSECTION            // флаг загрузки 
);
```

Подробнее о `LoadImage` [тут](http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Resourse/fn_loadimage.htm).

Функция AlphaBlend принимает предъумноженное изображение (`premultiplied`) и просто загрузить изображение не прокатит. Так как мы создали, при загрузке изображения, `DIB` секцию, то произведем предъумножение каждой компоненты цвета (32bpp) на коэффициент alpha-канала по формуле:

коэффициент alpha: `float fAlpha = (Pixel[i] >> 24) / 255.0f;`

а затем перебирая точки умножаем все на этот коэффициент. Привожу код:

```
// Производит пред-умножение точек на альфа канал в DIB секции изображения
void PreMultiplyBitmapAlpha(HBITMAP hBmp)
{
    // получаем информацию об загруженном bitmap
    BITMAP bm = { 0 };
    GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

    // для удобства записывает указатель на массив точек 0xARGB / 0xB 0xG 0xR 0xA
    DWORD* Pixel = (DWORD*)bm.bmBits;

    for (LONG i = 0; i < bm.bmHeight * bm.bmWidth; i++)

    {
        // вычисляем коэффициент альфа канала
        float fAlpha = (Pixel[i] >> 24) / 255.0f;

        // умножаем каждую компоненту пикселя на коэффициент 
        // альфа-канала и перезаписываем
        Pixel[i] = (Pixel[i] & 0xFF000000)              |   // 0xaa000000
            (BYTE(GetBValue(Pixel[i]) * fAlpha) << 16)  |   // 0x00rr0000
            (BYTE(GetGValue(Pixel[i]) * fAlpha) << 8)   |   // 0x0000gg00
            (BYTE(GetRValue(Pixel[i]) * fAlpha));           // 0x000000bb
    }
}
```

Примечание: в качестве параметра принимает `hbitmap` изображения с `DIB` секцией

В завершении скармливаем обработанное изображение в `AlphaBlend` :

```
// создаем совместимый DC с DC окна и связываем его с изображением 
// с пред-умноженным альфа-каналом
HDC hSrcDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
SelectObject(hSrcDC, hBitmap);

BITMAP bm = { 0 };
GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

BLENDFUNCTION bf = { 0 };
bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
bf.BlendFlags = 0;
bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 0xff; // общая прозрачность
bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA; // используется прозрачность 
                               // альфа канала для каждой точки 

// выводим на экран с учетом альфа-канала
AlphaBlend(
    hDC, 0, 20, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight,
    hSrcDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight,
    bf
);

DeleteDC(hSrcDC);
```

Примечание: если не хочется тянуть функцию `AlphaBlend` из библиотеки `msimg32.dll`, можно использовать ее аналог из все той же библиотеки `gdi32.dll`
но с префиксом `Gdi`: `GdiAlphaBlend`, `GdiTransparentBlt`, `GdiGradientFill`  и т.д.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Функция `LoadBitmap` не может считывать `32-битные` `bmp` файлы.

Для того, чтобы считать, необходимо уже пользоваться сторонней библиотекой. Например `EasyBMP`( http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/ ).

Чтобы скомпилировать с ней проект, кидаете все её файлы в папку с вашим проектом, и подключаете `.cpp` файл к файлам исходного кода.

А далее уже используете функцию `LoadAlphaBmp`, как в данном коде:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "EasyBMP.h"

HBITMAP Create32Bmp(int width, int height, DWORD* &mas) 
{
    /* Структура для того, чтобы связать картинку с массивом. */
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * 4;

    return CreateDIBSection(CreateCompatibleDC(NULL), 
            &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &mas, NULL, 0);
}

HBITMAP LoadAlphaBmp(char* name, int &width, int &height, DWORD* &mas) 
{
    BMP AnImage;
    AnImage.ReadFromFile(name);

    width = AnImage.TellWidth();
    height = AnImage.TellHeight();

    HBITMAP hbmp = Create32Bmp(width, height, mas);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            RGBApixel pix = AnImage.GetPixel(i, j);

            // mas - массив пикселей, обращаться к нему можно таким образом:
            DWORD pixel = pix.Alpha;
            pixel = (pixel << 8) + pix.Red;
            pixel = (pixel << 8) + pix.Green;
            pixel = (pixel << 8) + pix.Blue;

            ((DWORD*)mas)[i + j*width] = pixel; 
        }
    }

    return hbmp;
}

int main() {
    // На этом тексте мы будем рисовать
    printf(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
    );

    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    int width, height;
    DWORD *mas1;

    // Считываем картинку из файла.
    HBITMAP hbmp1 = LoadAlphaBmp("img4.bmp", width, height, mas1);
    HDC hdc1 = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc1, hbmp1));

    BLENDFUNCTION blendFn = {};
    blendFn.BlendOp             = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blendFn.BlendFlags          = 0;
    blendFn.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blendFn.AlphaFormat         = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, 
               hdc1, 0, 0, width, height, 
               blendFn);

    Sleep(3000);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Для рисования использовался рисунок(который можно скачать отсюда: http://my-files.ru/32qs23 . Он везде показывается черным, но на самом деле этот `bmp` файл `32-битный` и имеет такие каналы:

[image: Степень красного, синего, зеленого и прозрачного оттенков изображения]

Результат будет таким:

[image: Результат]

(Ребят, помогите, кто может - сделайте нормальные ссылки, сайт ругается что недостаточно репутации, буду очень благодарен.)

Comment: Для такой примитивной операции, как загрузка одного bitmap'a, не имеет смысла тянуть стороннюю DLL'ку, Вот ежели требуется серьезная работа по обработке изображений, то тогда можно подтянуть в плоть до Qt и DirectX

Comment: Это не DLL, это библиотека из 5 файлов(4 h и 1 cpp, 60 КБ кода), предназначенная исключительно для считывания и записи .bmp файлов. В бинарном виде она места занимает совсем немного.